# sendSynchronousRequest is deprecated in ios 9

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Xcode says that `sendSynchronousRequest` is now deprecated.

How should I replace it?

```
let postData:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
let postLength:NSString = String( postData.length )
let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = postData
request.setValue(postLength as String, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var response: NSURLResponse?
var urlData: NSData?
do {
    urlData = try NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response)
} catch _ as NSError {
    urlData = nil
} catch {
    fatalError()
}
```

Comment: USe NSURLSession instead of NSURLConnection

Comment: If only there was some way to search the internet using some key words.  http://bfy.tw/286i

Comment: i am not stupid i saw that other question but i didn't understand selected answer there lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example,
You should use NSURLSession, with Request.

```
     func testPost(sender: UIButton) {
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8080/iOSServer/ios/helloworld/swiftCalculator")!)
            request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let d = "4"
            let data = "x=4&y=\(d)"
            request.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
            let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
                if let data = data{
                    print("data =\(data)")
                }
                if let response = response {
                print("url = \(response.URL!)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                let httpResponse = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")

                //if you response is json do the following
                  do{
                    let resultJSON = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions())
                    let arrayJSON = resultJSON as! NSArray
                    for value in arrayJSON{
                        let dicValue = value as! NSDictionary
                        for (key, value) in dicValue {
                            print("key = \(key)")
                            print("value = \(value)")
                        }
                    }

                }catch _{
                    print("Received not-well-formatted JSON")
                }
            }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
```

Notice it is not necessary to use the request. you can have a data task with URL, but I added the request because in your code, you have set some headers in the request.

Notice using the `completionHandler` which will be called when your server responses by http response.

Comment: how to assign response value to urlData(NSData) ?

Comment: my code will check response like this  if ( urlData != nil ) {
                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse!;

                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                {

Comment: @RULE101 i updated my code to tell you how to get the url and the response code. in my code i have printed them, but you can do whatever check you want. if you still need anything else ,kindly tell me

Comment: OK when i run code i get this on this line let jsonData:NSDictionary = (try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers )) as! NSDictionary ERROR: cannot convert value type of NSURLresponse to NSData

Comment: response is a JSON by the way

Comment: @RULE101 okay i updated my answer to include a json response

Comment: for Json, it should be another question. If my answer helps you, please accept it and start another question and I will be happy to help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91403/discussion-between-rule101-and-william-kinaan).